# How to copy similar html into every page in jQuery

Tags: jquery, templates, inheritance, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a bootstrap webpage, and I'd like to create the top bar only once, and then include it on every page.  In Django, this was easy with template inheritance.  I could just create a new tag in the base page, and include it on every page I wanted it on.  Now I'm using only jQuery, so I'm trying to figure out a way to do this here.

I've looked at [jQuery tmpl](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-tmpl/) but it seems like thats not exactly what I want, because I want the same code being copied over every time.

For now, lets say this is my header:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I want to replace it with a template so it is simply copied onto the page.  Suggestions?

Comment: JQuery is not a web application framework.  It is more of a DOM manipulation tool.  You should look into something like Angular.js or Knockout.js

Comment: You are using JSP, PHP or ASP.Net?

Comment: All I want to do is reproduce some html on every page, not worried about any custom data for now

Comment: what about moving that into a header.html for instance and call it using jQuery `.load()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out a way to do it in jQuery, similarly to what @JFK suggests.

I created a separate html file called topbar.html with my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in my index.html, in addition to jquery, I also added

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
```

To include the tmpl function.  Then I could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('topbar.html', function(template) {

        // Use that stringified template with $.tmpl() and 
        //  inject the rendered result into the body.
        console.log(template);
        $("#topbar").html(template);
    });

</script>
```

Very simple once I understood what the jQuery tmpl was all about.  You can then additionally pass in extra parameters to tmpl to customize this template.  But I didn't need anything that fancy for now